# What exactly does the admin install script do?

Tags: magento2, installation, cli

I have been facing a strange issue with the magento 2 CLI installer and, after some investigation a doubt came up:

While using magento 1 it was totally possible to have your codebase copied over to a server, a mysql dump imported, `app/etc/local.xml` adjusted and the shop would be up and running.

But magento 2 seems to be different. While trying to bypass the install process, I have taken the following steps:

> 1. Copy codebase, adjusted permissions
> 2. Composer update and install
> 3. Adjustments made to app/etc/env.php
> 4. Enabled modules through CLI command
> 5. Imported DB dump, adjusting urls

After these steps, even though all modules were enabled, the shop was not installed according to error messages found in the log. Also, some very basic functions such as cache cleaning and reindexing are not available through the CLI.

I have gone through the contents of the files under app/etc/, comparing it with a running store, and the contents are identical. The codebase between these two shops are the same, btw.

What am I missing from this manual install process?

Gabriel

Comment: You can post the error log here?

Comment: @K What error log are you referring to? The question is about the inner workings of the install cli script. The error log was simply telling me "the shop is still not installed" (those are my words, but that is what is what it said). The error i had while using the install script was a MySQL has gone away while importing the data for the Magento_Directory module (yes, i had adjusted php and mysql settings to support long execution, memory and packets...)

Comment: **a MySQL has gone away while importing the data** => Try to re-import again and change http://piwik.org/faq/troubleshooting/faq_183/

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh Thanks, but i have already tried that as well